# Email Validation in Registrraion Form in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have One Register-form for creating Account.In Email Field How Can i Check Enter Email is Real Email Id or Fake Email Id without Sent Any Email.And Also when User Leave The Field Validation will be start.Any idea please Share me....

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: You may simply use `html5` `type="email"` and it will do all validation for you.

Comment: The simple answer is you CAN'T. You can check email address format but not magically knowing if this is a real email address.

Comment: that's why user registrations usually involve email verification or mobile text message verification to approve they are dealing with real people.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/46155/6568620

Comment: This Camel Case whY?

Comment: Thank you for your Replay.i have an doubt in case i enter<fgnj@njnn.dfm>this is correct format but fake id it is Acceptable my form .Any idea to Avoid to this problem....

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this work with **js**(without sedn email):

i recommend to send a code to your user rmail and verify that.

this way is good to valid email and register user.

**note** : if you want to know is the email is in email pattern you can do with html and js :

**html way :**

```
<input type="email" name="email"  placeholder="Your email">
```

**js way :**

[How to validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-email-address-in-javascript#)

Comment: Thank you for your Replay.i have an doubt in case i enter<fgnj@njnn.dfm>this is correct format but fake id it is Acceptable my form .Any idea to Avoid to this problem....